# Haxe & NME: fastest method for per pixel bitmap manipulation

Tags: haxe

This is a small project for testing pixel level manipulation performance of NME for different builds (Windows c++, Flash).

It uses **`BitmapData.setPixel`** to modify the pixels one by one (320x240 for every frame). The **C++ build runs at 22 FPS**, and the **flash build around ~100 FPS**. Whats the reason for the huge performance drop for the C++ build compared to flash? How could I improve the code to get higher FPS using the C++ build?

### Mandelbrot.hx

```hx
import nme.display.Sprite;
import nme.display.Bitmap;
import nme.display.BitmapData;
import nme.text.TextField;
import nme.events.Event;
import nme.events.TimerEvent;
import nme.utils.Timer;
import nme.geom.Matrix;
import nme.geom.Rectangle;
import nme.utils.ByteArray;

class Mandelbrot
{
    public static function main() : Void
    {
        new Mandelbrot();
    }

    public var pixels:Array<Array<Int>>;

    public var colorModifier:Int;
    private var bitmapData:BitmapData;
    private var bigBitmapData:BitmapData;

    private var fps:TextField;

    private var width:Int;
    private var height:Int;
    private var matrix:Matrix;

    public function new() 
    {
        width = 320; //Std.int(flash.Lib.current.stage.stageWidth/2);
        height = 240; //Std.int(flash.Lib.current.stage.stageHeight/2);

        var scale:Float = 2;//flash.Lib.current.stage.stageWidth/width;
        matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.scale(scale, scale);

        var setBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
        bitmapData = new BitmapData( width , height , false , 0x000000 );
        bigBitmapData = new BitmapData( nme.Lib.current.stage.stageWidth , nme.Lib.current.stage.stageHeight , false , 0x000000 );

        setBitmap.bitmapData = bigBitmapData;

        nme.Lib.current.addChild( setBitmap );

        var maxIterations:Int = 128;

        pixels = new Array();


        var beforeTime = nme.Lib.getTimer();

        var xtemp;
        var iteration;
        var x0:Float = 0;
        var y0:Float = 0;
        for(ix in 0...width) {
            pixels[ix] = new Array();
            for(iy in 0...height) {
                    x0 = 0;
                    y0 = 0;
                    iteration = 128;

                    while ( x0*x0 + y0*y0 <= 4  &&  iteration > 0 ) 
                    {
                        xtemp = x0*x0 - y0*y0 + (ix-14*5000)/50000;
                        y0 = 2*x0*y0 + (iy-(height/0.6))/50000;
                        x0 = xtemp;

                        iteration--;
                    }

                    pixels[ix][iy] = iteration;
            }
        }

        var afterTime = nme.Lib.getTimer();

        var tf = new TextField();
        tf.width = 400;
        tf.text = "Generating fractal took "+(afterTime-beforeTime)+" ms";
        nme.Lib.current.addChild(tf);

        fps = new TextField();
        fps.width = 400;
        fps.y = 10;
        fps.text = "FPS: ";
        nme.Lib.current.addChild(fps);

        colorModifier = 2;
        var timer:haxe.Timer = new haxe.Timer(10);

        runLoop();
        timer.run = runLoop;
    }

    public function runLoop() {
        var r:Int=0, b:Int=0, g:Int=0;
        var pixel:Int = 0;

        var beforeTime = nme.Lib.getTimer();

        for(iy in 0...height) {
            for(ix in 0...width) {
                pixel = pixels[ix][iy];
                r = pixel + colorModifier;
                g = pixel + colorModifier + r;
                b = pixel + colorModifier + g;
                bitmapData.setPixel(ix, iy, (r<<16 | g<<8 | b));
            }
        }

        bigBitmapData.draw(bitmapData, matrix, null, null, null, false);
        var afterTime = nme.Lib.getTimer();
        fps.text = "FPS: "+Math.round(1000/(afterTime-beforeTime));

        colorModifier += 2;
        if(colorModifier > 65530)
                colorModifier = 0;


    }
}
```

### Mandelbrot.nmml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
  <app
     file="Mandelbrot.hx"
     title="Mandelbrot sample"
     package="org.haxe.nme.mandelbrot"
     version="1.0.0"
     company="nme" 
     main="Mandelbrot"
  />
  <window
        width="640"
        height="480"
        orientation="landscape"
        fps="60"
        background="0xffffff"
        resizeable="true"
        hardware="true"
    />
  <classpath name="." />
  <haxelib name="nme" />
  <ndll name="std" />
  <ndll name="regexp" />
  <ndll name="zlib" />
  <ndll name="nme" haxelib="nme" />
  <setenv name="SHOW_CONSOLE"/>
</project>
```

Comment: This isn't C++ code.  We need to see what C++ HaXe is putting out before we can analyze the situation.  Then, how is the C++ compiled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look into the `nme.Memory` API. The idea is to create a `ByteArray` with the correct size (or get it from a `BitmapData`), select it as the current virtual memory space and manipulate its bytes directly.

You'll get an approximately 10x speed boost with Flash and it should be way faster with the CPP target too. **Don't forget to compile in Release mode** or method inlining will be disabled and performances will suffer a lot.

Basic usage example (untested code) :

```hx
var rect:Rectangle = bitmapData.rect;

// 32bits integer = 4 bytes
var size:Int = bitmapData.width * bitmapData.height * 4;

// The virtual memory space we'll use
var pixels:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

// CPP does not support setting the length property directly
#if (cpp) pixels.setLength(size);
#else pixels.length = size; #end

// Select the memory space (call it once, not every frame)
Memory.select(pixels);

// And in your loop set your color
// Color is in BGRA mode, nme.Memory can only be used in little endian mode.
Memory.setI32((y * width + x) * 4, color);

// When you're done, render the BitmapData
// (don't forget to reset the ByteArray position)
pixels.position = 0;
bitmapData.setPixels(rect, pixels);
```

Keep in mind this is a very basic code example. In your case, you'd need to adapt it and actually use a double sized `ByteArray` because you need to store the iteration count too. Nested loops can be optimized in your main loop and you can avoid a lot of extra index/address computations :

```hx
// Note the size * 2 !
// First part of the ByteArray will be used to store the iteration count,
// the second part to draw the pixels.
#if (cpp) pixels.setLength(size * 2);
#else pixels.length = size * 2; #end

Memory.select(pixels);

// First loop storing iteration count
for (iy in 0...height)
{
    for (ix in 0...width)
    {
        // ... do some stuff ...
        Memory.setI32((iy * width + ix) << 2, iteration);
    }
}

// In your runLoop :
for (i in 0...(height * width))
{
    // Get the iteration count
    var pixel:Int = Memory.getI32(i << 2);

    r = pixel + colorModifier;
    g = pixel + colorModifier + r;
    b = pixel + colorModifier + g;

    // Note that we're writing the pixel in the second part of our ByteArray
    Memory.setI32(size + (i << 2), r | g << 8 | b << 16);
}

// Sets the position to the second part of our ByteArray
pixels.position = size;
bitmapData.setPixels(rect, pixels);
```

And this is it. If you really don't want to use Alchemy Opcodes on the Flash target, the next fastest way to blit pixels is to use `getVector()` / `setVector()` from the `BitmapData` class. But it's really not as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Array itself is not true liner array in flash, more like a map.
For the per-pixel manipulation I can recommend to use getVector/setVector api of the BitmapData class, which can retrieve (and assign) a rectangular area of the image as flat pixel data. In which case you can access individual pixels in the vector as:

```
pixels[ix + image_width*iy] = <argb32>
```

Also, instead of constructing an intermediate Array of Arrays it would be faster to assign pixels directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [ByteArray](http://www.haxenme.org/api/types/nme/utils/ByteArray.html). It would be faster in Flash and C++, I think.